# How to format a LocalTime variable

Tags: java, swing, date, nsdateformatter, jodatime

I am quite new to Java windowbuilder, and this is part of my first project.

```
String starttime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What time would you like to start your revision ? (ie:12:24) ");

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(starttime,dtf);
```

I want to convert the format of start from `("HH:mm:ss..etc")` to `("HH:mm")`, but I get an error for the `LocalTime.parse` for some reason. Any suggestions what I should do.

I'm using Joda Time

Comment: What is the input when it fails? And what is the error?

Comment: Please share that error

Comment: it isnt the input. It says: The method parse(java.lang.String, org.joda.time.format DateTimeFormatter ) in the type LocalTime is not applicable for the arguements (java.lang.String,, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incorrectly referencing [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Use JodaTime's [`forPattern`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern-java.lang.String-)

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(starttime, dtf);
System.out.println(dtf.print(start));
```

or simply

```
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(startTime).toString("HH:mm"));
```

Comment: The error no longer appears, but the value of start still shows seconds and milliseconds (which I do not want). Do you have any suggestions as to how I can get start to just hours and minutes ?

Comment: use the `DateTimeFormatter` you created in this question when displaying the time as shown in the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes built into Java, not *Joda-Time*.

```
LocalTime.parse( "23:45:12.123456789" )       // Represent a time-of-day without date and without time zone. Parsing standard ISO 8601 format HH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSS in 24-hour clock. Returns a `LocalTime` object.
         .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES )   // Produce a new value, based on original, but lopping off any seconds or fractional-second. Returns another `LocalTime` object.
         .toString()                          // Generate a `String` with text representing the value of this date-time value, using standard ISO 8601 format. Returns a `String` object.
```

> 23:45
>
> but I get an error for the LocalTime.parse

Your specified formatting pattern must match the input string – yours was a mismatch.

As seen in code above, if inputting standard ISO 8601 format, the built-in `LocalTime.parse` feature handles variations. So no need to bother specifying a formatting pattern at all.

## Details

The [Answer by Reimeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825237/642706) is correct, but uses the outmoded *Joda-Time* classes. While an excellent library, its creators (principally Stephen Colebourne) went on to create the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, and advises migration to *java.time*.

## *java.time*

If your user’s inputs go by the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, you need not specifying a formatting pattern to parse the string inputs. This means 24-hour clock using hours 1-23, and a leading padding zero for hours 1-9: 01-09. The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input1 = "23:45";
String input2 = "23:45:12";
String input3 = "23:45:12.123456789";

LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse( input1 );
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse( input2 );
LocalTime lt3 = LocalTime.parse( input3 );

System.out.println( lt1 );
System.out.println( lt2 );
System.out.println( lt3 );
```

> 23:45
>
> 23:45:12
>
> 23:45:12.123456789

### Suppress display

If you want to suppress display of any seconds or fractional-second, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. That class is well-documented, and has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more discussion and examples.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = myLocalTime.format( f ) ;
```

> 23:45

### Truncate

If you want to drop any seconds or fractional-second from your date-time value, truncate.

```
LocalTime.parse( "23:45:12" )
         .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) 
         .toString()
```

> 23:45

…or…

```
LocalTime.parse( "23:45:12.123456789" )
         .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) 
         .toString()
```

> 23:45

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).